# Can an ~/.ssh/config file use variables?

Tags: bash, ssh, config

I am writing an SSH config file and want to perform a bit of logic. For example:

```
Host myhost1
    ProxyCommand ssh -A {choose randomly between [bastion_host1] and [bastion_host2]} -W %h:%p
```

Is it possible to achieve the above using (bash?) variables? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `ProxyCommand` can be a shell script.

```sh
host myhost1
    ProxyCommand $HOME/bin/selecthost %h %p
```

And then in `~/bin/selecthost`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
hosts=(bastion1 bastion2)
    
onehost=${hosts[$RANDOM % ${#hosts[@]}]}
    
ssh -x -a -q ${2:+-W $1:$2} $onehost
```

Untested. Your mileage may vary. May contain nuts.

Per comments, I've also tested the following, and it works nicely:

```sh
host myhost1 myhost2
    ProxyCommand bash -c 'hosts=(bastion1 bastion2); ssh -xaqW%h:22 ${hosts[$RANDOM % ${#hosts[@]}]}'
```

Of course, this method doesn't allow you to specify a custom port per host. You could add that to the logic of a separate shell script if your SSH config matches multiple hosts in the same `host` entry.

Comment: In this script, the `$onehost` variable is set by selecting a random array element from a bash array.  Your ProxyCommand is executed by your shell, so as long as your shell is bash, I don't see why you couldn't include the entire functionality of this script on a single line, though I haven't tried it.  I answered this way because I don't know that you're using bash as your default shell.  (On my system, I use bash for programming, but tcsh is my default shell.)

Comment: "May contain nuts" Gave me a laugh!

Comment: Would you be able to point out [what I'm doing wrong here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55579583/241211)?

Comment: Upvoted for nut warnings too. Six year old answers still fresh!

Answer (score 10):

In `~/.ssh/config` you cannot have much logic, and no Bash. The manual for this file is in `man ssh_config`, and it makes no mention of such feature.

What you can do is create a script that will have the logic you need, and make your ssh configuration call that script.
Something along the lines of:

```
ProxyCommand ~/bin/ssh-randomly.sh [bastion_host1] [bastion_host2]
```

And write a Bash script `~/bin/ssh-randomly.sh` to take two hostname parameters, select one of them randomly, and run the real `ssh` command with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 7):

No; `.ssh/config` is not processed by any outside program. You'll need a shell function along the lines of

```
ssh () {
    (( $RANDOM % 2 )) && bastion=bastion_host1 || bastion=bastion_host2

    command ssh -A "$bastion" "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled within ssh config by using a helper app.  For example,

```
Host myhost match exec "randprog"
     hostname host1
Host myhost
     hostname host2
```

and then `randprog` will randomly return 1 or 0 (0 will match the first line, giving host1).